# Run wso2 Windows Service

Tags: java, cmd, wso2, wso2-esb

I am relative new in wso2 and are having some little problems with a project. I was able to create a service in my local machine. But when tried to make the same in the server of the project, i had some bugs. The same follow bellow:

```
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:21|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-11.03
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:21|OS   : Windows Server 2012 R2/6.3/amd64
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:21|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_131
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|set state IDLE->STARTING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|Controller State: UNKNOWN -> WAITING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|working dir c:\omniPOS
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|create script: scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|found script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|started process with pid 8528
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:22|set state STARTING->RUNNING
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|[INFO] StandardFileSystemManager - Using "c:\omniPOS\wso2\tmp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|platform null
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Controller State: WAITING -> ESTABLISHED
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Controller State: ESTABLISHED -> LOGGED_ON
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|[2017-07-18 17:26:23,789] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Invalid Bundle found in the dropins directory: com.typesafe.config.config_1.0.0.jar
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|[2017-07-18 17:26:23,794] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Invalid Bundle found in the dropins directory: hadoop-client.config_1.0.0.jar
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|[2017-07-18 17:26:23,795] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Invalid Bundle found in the dropins directory: org.wso2.carbon.logging.propfile_1.0.0.jar
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Trigger found: Exception in line: 
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|start script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|end script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.executeMain(WrapperJVMMain.java:53)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.main(WrapperJVMMain.java:36)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Trigger found: Exception in line: 
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonLauncher.buildInitialPropertyMap(CarbonLauncher.java:201)
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|start script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonLauncher.launch(CarbonLauncher.java:74)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.launchCarbon(Main.java:160)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:94)
INFO|8528/0|"WSO2 Server"|17-07-18 17:26:23|    ... 12 more
```

If anyone could help me i would stay quite grateful.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the jars inside the dropins directory are corrupted for some reason. Remove all jars in `repository/components/dropins` directory and try again. If it doesn't work, plz attach those jars.

Edit: As per [this Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15242), the error can happen when `CARBON_HOME` has a trailing slash. Check that and remove it if that's the case.

Comment: Hello Bhathiya. First of all, thank you for your help. I was able to solve some of the problems. I think the mainly problem was that the CARBON_HOME, was configured with '\' in the end. Example: 'C:\wso2\', and it don't let the cmd found the correct way to the .jar's. I think probably was something like it. Now it are running, but my problem is other, even with the .conf of the 'EI611' tutorial, the service don't run the correct links that i need, i will explain better in a answer, to put my conf archive.